# Best programming languages for implementing Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to build a decentralised payment gateway system using blockchain. I researched on the internet for best and secure programming languages to build the system, and I was confused between Java, C++, JavaScript, Solidity, Simplicity and Python.

I got C++, Solidity and Simplicity the best programming languages and then Python, followed by Java and JavaScript.

I am confused on how to build the system. Does it necessary to have a web application or Just the server hosted with IBM.

I know this question sounds stupid, but please give me some advice on getting started.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is really broad, can you try narrowing it down to something specific. Take a look at the [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right question would be which Blockchain Platform to choose for your application. Each Blockchain platform has its own way of communicating with the client application.

Creating a Blockchain-based application would require knowledge in networking, containerization, REST API, and programming languages like Solidity, Javascript, and Go to write Smart Contracts and Front End.

I'd suggest you do some research on blockchain platforms like Hyperledger Fabric and Ethereum.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, Bibek for your awesome response.